# How do I determine the database name of a Google Cloud SQL database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL instance. Under the "Overview" tab, there's a "Connect to this instance" card with four fields:

```
Public IP address
Private IP address
Associated networking
Connection name
```

I'd like to construct a connection string in my python app to connect to this database. My connection string is formatted like:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{DB_NAME}"
```

I know the `username` and `password` as I created a user under Cloud SQL -> Users -> Add User account.

I know the `host` is *probably* the `Private IP address` from the above card info.

I *suspect* the port is `3306` based on nothing concrete, it's just the most consistent number I see repeated throughout examples.

I believe I got the above portions of the string correct, because when I try to run the Python app, I get this error:

```
 Unknown database {{Connection name}}
```

Where Connection name is the value I got from the info card. I thought that was the database name, but now I don't know. It looks like `my-app-name:us-central1:my-sql-instance-name`

I tried both the entire value, as well as only what's after the second `:` in the string (`my-sql-instance-name`). Neither worked.

**How do I determine the database name of my Google Cloud SQL instance?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login to the Google Cloud Console GUI.

Click the Hamburger menu, scroll down to **Databases**. Click **SQL**.

You should find a list of SQL instances. Click on the instance name.

In the left column, click on **Databases**.

You will then see a list of databases. Several of the databases are created by MySQL such as **information_schema**. Make note of the database name and then use that name in your connection string.

[image: Google Cloud SQL Databases]

**You can also use the CLI:**

List the Cloud SQL instances:

```
gcloud sql instances list --project=PROJECT_ID
```

[gcloud sql instances list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/list)

List the databases:

```
gcloud sql databases list --instance=INSTANCE_NAME --project=PROJECT_ID
```

[gcloud sql databases list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/databases/list)

Note: Your connection string is using IP:PORT. This means that you also need to whitelist your IP address(es) in order to connect to the SQL instance. I recommend that you use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy instead. Some services such as Cloud Run already have the SQL Auth Proxy built-in. Consult the service's documentation on how to connect to Cloud SQL.

[About the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)